ITextRenderer SetPDFXConformance input values in Flying saucer?
I need to create a PDF/A3B from an HTML.
I'm using Java 22 and flying-saucer.
HTML parsing is OK and a "standard" pdf is created.
To set PDF/A conformance I need to use the ITextReader.setPDFXConformance method, that wants an integer as input parameter, but I cannot find anywhere if there is an enum or some integer wrapper to define various PDF/A flavours. IText's PDFAConformanceLevel enum is not defined here, and it would not be of any help, being a 2-string enum and not an integer.
Here's the snippet I use to create PDF and embed fonts for /A compliance. I tried some random numbers (4 in the sample) but giving the output PDF to veraPDF it seems not to be a PDF/A document.
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("c:/windows/fonts/Tahoma.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("c:/windows/fonts/Verdana.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
renderer.setDocumentFromString(customHtmlContent);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(new FileOutputStream("C:/temp/dest/doc.pdf"));
renderer.setPDFXConformance(4);
renderer.finishPDF();
System.out.println("PDF generated from custom HTML content.");


Try using the constants in the PdfWriter class.

@dan1st Thanks for the reply, looking for it I discovered that flying-saucer only supports PDF/A1b and PDF/A1a, so I need to switch to something else.

@K J I'm not that happy to embed command line tools in the solution, since I'm adding complexity (and reducing performance) to a module that has to be run several times in a web app backend microservice. I'll try to pursue what you are suggesting, though, and see if the balance result/performance will be good indeed.
